# Альтернатива _kbhit(), _getch() и GetKeyState(). Windows Keyboard. C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, клавиатура

Я работаю с клавиатурой так (`_kbhit()`, `_getch()`):

```
while (true)        // Цикл сильно грузит процессор
{                   //        ^
    if (_kbhit())   // Этот вызов не блокирующий
    {
        char ch = tolower(_getch());

        switch (ch) 
        {
            case 'r':
                // ...
                break;
            default:
                // ...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

или так (`GetKeyState()`):

```
void keyAnaliz()
{
    enum 
    {
        e_firstIndex = 0,
        e_size = 255,
        e_lastIndex = e_firstIndex + e_size,                    
    };

    bool prevCheckedKeys[e_size];
    memset(prevCheckedKeys, true, e_size);

    bool checkedKeys[e_size];
    memset(checkedKeys, false, e_size);

    while (isPlay)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e_size; ++i)
        {
            int b                = i + e_firstIndex;
            char ch              = char(b);
            const short keyState = GetKeyState(b);
            bool isChecked       = keyState & 0001; 
            checkedKeys[i]       = isChecked;

            if (prevCheckedKeys[i] != checkedKeys[i])
            {
                cout << ch;
                prevCheckedKeys[i] = checkedKeys[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но оба способа меня не устраивают, так как сильно грузят процессор. Хотелось бы обрабатывать прерывания от клавиатуры и вызывать callback функции.
На MSDN есть огромный раздел «[Клавиатурный ввод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)», я только начал его изучать.

В какую сторону копать и где искать? Может кто-то привет примеры готовых решений.

Найдено решение с использованием `SetWindowsHookEx()`:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x500
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

HHOOK   g_hHook;
HANDLE  g_hEvent;
UINT    g_uKey = VK_CAPITAL;
UINT    g_uDisableKey = VK_LMENU;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *ks = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        if (ks->vkCode == g_uKey && !(GetKeyState(g_uDisableKey) & 0x8000))
        {
            if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
                AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL), TRUE);
                HWND hWnd_thread = GetFocus();
                if (hWnd_thread)
                    hWnd = hWnd_thread;

                if (hWnd)
                    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, 0, (LPARAM)HKL_NEXT);
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void failed(const TCHAR *msg)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, msg, _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    ExitProcess(1);
}

void CALLBACK TimerCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
    if (WaitForSingleObject(g_hEvent, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        PostQuitMessage(0);
}

void cmdLineParse(int argc, wchar_t ** argv)
{
    argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
    if (argv != NULL && argc >= 2)
    {
        UINT uCmdKey = _wtoi(argv[1]);
        if (uCmdKey >= 0x01 && uCmdKey <= 0xFE)
            g_uKey = uCmdKey;

        if (argc >= 3)
        {
            UINT uDisableKey = _wtoi(argv[2]);
            if (uDisableKey >= 0x01 && uDisableKey <= 0xFE)
                g_uDisableKey = uDisableKey;
        }
    }
    LocalFree(argv);
}

void applicationIsAlreadyRunning()
{
    g_hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, _T("HaaliLSwitch"));
    if (g_hEvent == NULL)
        failed(_T("CreateEvent()"));

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        failed(_T("LSwitch is already running!"));
    }
}

void resolve(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    MSG msg;

    cmdLineParse(argc, argv);

    applicationIsAlreadyRunning();

    if (SetTimer(NULL, 0, 500, TimerCallback) == 0)     // Не понял зачем это нужно?
        failed(_T("SetTimer()"));

    g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHook, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
    if (!g_hHook)
        failed(_T("SetWindowsHookEx()"));

    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hHook);
    CloseHandle(g_hEvent);
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Осталось несколько вопросов:

1. Зачем по таймеру вызывать функцию `TimerCallback()` и что в ней происходит? Без нее решение работает нормально.
2. Не совсем понял, зачем [используется связка](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?53) `GetMessage()`, `TranslateMessage()` и `DispatchMessage()`. Можете посоветовать хорошую книгу по WinApi, чтобы в этом разобраться?

Comment: Вы запустили холостой цикл, конечно, он грузит процессор. А почему вы не обрабатываете оконные сообщения? Вам как раз нужен [`WM_CHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276(v=vs.85).aspx) (или [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Я ранее не работал с WinApi. Можете простым языком объяснить концепцию оконных сообщений?

Comment: Зачем используется связка GetMessage, TranslateMessage, DispatchMessage не совсем понял http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?53 . Можете посоветовать хорошую книгу по WinApi, чтобы в этом разобраться?

Comment: GetMessage уходит в ожидание до прихода оконного сообщения. TranslateMessage преобразовывает его (например, превращает WM_KEYDOWN в WM_CHAR). DispatchMessage пересылает сообщение из цикла сообщений оконной процедуре (к одной очереди сообщений может быть «прикреплено» несколько окон).

Comment: Есть [документация в MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632586(v=vs.85).aspx) (но она на английском). Хорошую книгу не знаю, если честно. Но я бы посоветовал всё же не писать на чистом WinAPI, а подняться на более высокий уровень. (Хотя бы MFC.)

Comment: TimerCallback это немного костыль, чтобы процесс завершался корректно. Вам это не нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте SetWindowHookEx.
Пример тут: https://github.com/MikalaiR/LSwitch/blob/master/lswitch.c

Comment: Что-то сложновато...

Answer (score 0):

- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,f2f74e891abe6be3
- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1153#issuecomment-139896374
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684961(v=vs.85).aspx

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>

char getch()
{
  static INPUT_RECORD cachedInputRecord;

  INPUT_RECORD r;

  if(cachedInputRecord.EventType == 1)
    {
    r = cachedInputRecord;
    if(cachedInputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount == 0)
      cachedInputRecord.EventType = -1;
    else
      cachedInputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount--;
    }
  else
  {
    DWORD n;

    while(true)
      {
      ReadConsoleInput(GetStdHandle(-10), &r, 1, &n);

      short keyCode = r.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;

      if(!(r.EventType == 1 && r.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown) && keyCode != 0x12) continue;

      char ch = r.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;

      if(ch == 0 && ((keyCode >= 0x10 && keyCode <= 0x12) || keyCode == 0x14 || keyCode == 0x90 || keyCode == 0x91)) continue;

      if(r.Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount > 1)
      {
        r.Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount--;
        cachedInputRecord = r;
      }

      break;
      }
   }

   return r.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;
}

int main()
{
  char ch =' ';

  for (int q=10; q; --q)
  {
    printf("Press %d keys (previous was %c)\n", q, ch);
    ch = getch();
  }

  return 0;
}
```